# Как правильно обновлять jwt?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony2, jwt

Хочу разобраться как правильно реализовать обновление jwt для web - приложения.

Путем гугления нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration.
Но как я понял там предлагают хранить в самом токене время, когда текущий токен нужно заблокировать и выдать новый.
Т.е. получается, что если токен украдут, то его можно использовать до бесконечности т.к. при наличии токена и истечении времени обновления, выдается новый валидный токен. **Или забиваем на проблему кражи токена, надеясь на HTTPS?**

Еще натыкался на схему с jwt и refresh токеном, типа новый jwt можно получить только если предъявить refresh токен. В такой схеме я видел следующую ситуацию:

1. Клиент делает запрос на сервер передавая уже просроченный jwt
2. Сервер отдает 401/403
3. Чтобы конечному пользователю не проходить аутентификацию снова,
   клиент ловит эту 401/403 ошибку и делает запрос на получение нового
   jwt предъявив refresh
4. Сервер выдает новый jwt (и возможно плюс новый refresh токен еще) и
   клиент повторяет запрос №1 но уже с валидным jwt и все почти
   счастливы.

Для конечного пользователя такая схема, скорее всего, будет выглядеть долгой загрузкой страницы.

**В итоге, как же правильно обновлять jwt, чтобы это было безопасно и конечный пользователь был доволен?**

Comment: Изучите данную статью: https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc#file-tokens-md

Comment: @artyom-norin, нашли правильный способ? Я тоже ищу сейчас ответ на этот вопрос, связанный с кражей токена.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте refresh токен, но задайте интервал времени до протухания jwt в котором клиентское приложение должно запросить новый jwt заранее, не дожидаясь истечения его срока годности. Если же пользователь давно не заходил в приложение и токен таки протух - ну ничего, подождёт несколько долей секунды в виде исключения.

Answer (score 1):

> Т.е. получается, что если токен украдут, то его можно использовать до бесконечности т.к. при наличии токена и истечении времени обновления, выдается новый валидный токен.

Сам сейчас задумался над этой проблемой. Получается что даже в черный список мы не можем занести украденный обновленный токен, так как мы его по сути не знаем, он же нигде не хранится.

Как вариант в токене сохранять какой-то уникальный идентификатор цепочки токенов (token_id = 357) и при обновлении новый токен будет с тем же идентификатором (token_id = 357), получится вся цепочка с одним идентификатором. Если токен будет украден и обновлен, то настоящий юзер зайдя по старому токену, получит форму аутентификации, после успешной отправки логина и пароля мы сможем заблокировать цепочку токенов по уникальному идентификатору (token_id = 357). А юзеру выдать новый токен с новым идентификатором цепочки (token_id = 358)

Comment: Подтверждением валидности токена является его секрет, который в любой момент можно отозвать.