# Правильное использование access и refresh token (JWT) в php

Tags: php, token, jwt, authenticationtoken

Всем привет. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с использованием JWT в своём проекте на php. Использую библиотеку [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt).
На данный момент получилось реализовать авторизацию через приложение на смартфоне. 
После успешной регистрации приложение получает jwt access_token (если я правильно понял) через `JWT::encode($token, $key);`. 
Также клиент может отправлять этот токен на сервер, который проверяет его корректность и например изменяет данные в БД.

Я достаточно много читал про JWT, но до конца всё равно не разобрался в принципе его работы.

У меня возникает сразу несколько вопросов.

1. Как корректно настроить переменные для JWT:

   ```
   $key = "your_secret_key";
   $iss = "http://any-site.org";
   $aud = "http://any-site.com";
   $iat = 1356999524;
   $nbf = 1357000000;
   ```

   Как это вижу я:

   ```
   $key - любая комбинация цифр, знаков, букв - то есть что-то типа соли.
   $iss - адрес сайта, который выдаёт токены (место расположения сервера)
   $aud - аналогичный адрес (но как я прочитал, для генерации access и refresh используют два разных сервера) 
   $iat - время создания (нужно изменять каждый раз, когда генерируется access token?) 
   $nbf - время жизни токена (какое время нужно использовать?)
   ```
2. Как формировать refresh токен?
   Судя по статьям про JWT.

   > **access_token** — токен, который нам нужно будет отправлять в шапке каждого запроса, для получения данных в ответ.
   >
   > **refresh_token** — токен, который нам нужно будет отправлять, для получения нового токена, когда истечет время жизни старого
3. Где хранить токены после получения?
   Я предполагаю, что access_token можно хранить в памяти смартфона и отправлять каждый раз, когда требуется его проверка со стороны сервера.
4. Как сохранять авторизацию пользователя после каждого запуска приложения? Я бы отправлял access_token каждый раз, когда зарегистрированный пользователь открывает приложение и если валидация на сервере прошла успешна - проводил авторизацию (по аналогии с cookies).

Для меня JWT на данный момент достаточно сложная тема, но если кто-то, кто уже работал с ним, подскажет, я буду благодарен.

Comment: посмотрите
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597442/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-jwt
и 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807619/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-refresh-token-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Payload — это любые данные, которые вы хотите передать в токене. Но стандарт предусматривает несколько зарезервированных полей:
iss — (issuer) издатель токена
sub — (subject) "тема", назначение токена,описываемый объект
aud — (audience) аудитория, получатели токена
exp — (expire time) срок действия токена
nbf — (not before) срок, до которого токен не действителен
iat — (issued at) время создания токена
jti — (JWT id) идентификатор токена

пример:
{
  "iss": " StuLux Team",
  "sub": "auth",
  "exp": 1505467756865,
  "iat": 1505467152065,
  "user": 3
}

2 - Пользователь логинится в приложении, передавая логин/пароль, в случае удачи создает запись в БД с рефреш токеном и временем его жизни, юзеру же возвращается сгенерированные сервером access и refresh токены JWT, для более подробного понимания можно разобрать примеры или использовать готовые решения библиотек с сайта https://jwt.io/#libraries.

3 - много холиваров на эту тему про хранение токенов JWT это вопрос уязвимости приложения так сказать, на клиенте access лежат в памяти приложения, refresh сетится в куке или ложится в локалсторедж

4 - для этого как раз и нужен refresh token

Более подробно можно почитать тут - https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc

Я лично для начала рекомендую хотя бы для тестов развернуть какие  то готовые решения и понять ход работы не делая велосипедов.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ)
Уточните, а чем в этом случае отличается хранение в памяти приложения и хранение в local storage?

Comment: рефреш токен имелось в виду что можно положить прямо на жесткий диск, в файле или бд, в случае с аксесс токеном то его сохранять никуда не рекомендуют, исключительно в памяти клиентского приложения, не в глобальных переменных к которым можно получить отовсюду доступ а в замыканиях. И все же для более детального понимания рекомендую изучить ссылку гит что дал выше, там можно получить исчерпывающее пособие за 15 минут чтения.

Comment: Вернулся к этому вопросу. С access token разобрался. В payload кидаю такую информацию: $payload = [
     'iat' => time(),
     'iss' => 'jwt', // название хоста
     'exp' => time() + 15,
     'userId' => $user['id']
    ];
Потом кодирую и вывожу в json: $token = JWT::encode($payload, SECRET_KEY);
Refresh token генерирую так: $random_string = bin2hex(random_bytes(40));
Отправляю клиенту оба токена.

Comment: Перед каждым запросом проверяю не просрочен ли access. Если не просрочен, всё ок, разрешаю доступ. Если просрочен - отправляю запрос на /refresh вместе с refresh токеном. Проверяю соответствует ли он тому, что находится в БД и не просрочен ли (сравниваю с датой создания в БД). Если просрочен или не найден, выкидываю форму авторизации. Если найден и такой же как пришёл, то создаю новый access и refresh и отправляю их клиенту. Правильно ли это?